# Gradually evoke functions from the list of functions (without generator)

Tags: python, list, function

I have a problem with enabling the functions in a list in a hangman. Here is the problem code sample - abbreviated because of its length:

```
board=[]#A matrix to which I append required letters

def func(list1):
    does sth with list1
    return list1

def func2(list2):
    does sth with list2
    return list2

def func3(list3):
    does sth with list3
    return list3

f1=func(board)
f2=func2(f1)
f3=func3(f2)

list_of_func=[f1, f2, f3]
count=0

if sth happens:
     print(list_of_func[count])
     count+=1
```

However, it doesn't print a board modified step by step, but the entirely changed board - changed by all functions. How can I stop Python from changing the whole board?

Comment: `board`, `list1`, `list2`, and `list3` are all just different names for the same list.  If you need to keep the history of changes to that list, you need to save a copy of it at each step, or have each function make a copy and modify that rather than modifying the original.

Comment: How can I do that?

Answer (score 0):

You are passing a reference to the same list around in your functions. That means, the list you modified in `func()` is the same that gets modified in the other functions.

You could create copies of the list, so you mantain a copy of the list after each step. You could use slice notation to achive this:

```
f1 = func(board[:])
f2 = func2(f1[:])
f3 = func3(f2[:])
```

Or the `list()` built-in:

```
f1 = func(list(board))
f2 = func2(list(f1))
f3 = func3(list(f2))
```

This way, `f1`, `f2` and `f3` will each hold a reference to a different list.